# How to combine two ROC curves into one graph?

Tags: r, plot, graph, roc

I am trying to plot two ROC curves into the same graph to compare the two visually.
I used the pROC package, but can't figure out how to combine the plots.

This is the code I used to calculate and plot the ROC

```
roc_1 <- pROC::roc(data = df, response = Mortality, predictor = Riskfactor, plot = TRUE)
roc_2 <- pROC::roc(data = df, response = Mortality, predictor = old_Riskfactor, plot = TRUE)
```

how could I combine both curves into one graph and add colour to differentiate them?

Comment: Include argument `add=TRUE` to the 2nd call to `pROC::roc`.

Comment: thanks, that works! is there a way to colour one of the ROCs?

Comment: Have you tried argument `col = "a color"` ? The function documentation says the graphics parameters are passed on to `plot.roc`, a S3 class method for objects of class `"roc"`. So this is base R graphics, see [`par`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html) for all parameters accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `add=TRUE` argument as mentioned in the comments.

However, a better idea is to build and plot the ROC curves separately:

```
# First build the ROC curves
roc_1 <- pROC::roc(data = df, response = Mortality, predictor = Riskfactor)
roc_2 <- pROC::roc(data = df, response = Mortality, predictor = old_Riskfactor)
# Then plot
plot(roc_1)
lines(roc_2, color="green")
```